# Characterize ideals in polynomial ring in terms of ideals in the coefficient ring.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and $A[x]$ the polynomial ring over $A$.

Given $I$ as an ideal of $A[x]$, we have the following informations:

1. For integers $0\leq d\leq n$, the set of degree $d$ coefficients in
   degree $n$ polynomial $$I_d^n = \{a_d\in A:
      a_0+...a_dx^d+...a_nx^n\in I\}$$ is an ideal in $A$, and
   $I_s^m\subset I_d^n$ if $m\leq n$, $s\leq d$ and $m-s = n-d$.

This would imply that the set $I^d_d$ of leading coefficients of polynomials in $I$ with degree $d$ is an ideal. Further more the set of leading coefficients  in $I$ is an ideal as the filtered union $I^L = \bigcup_{d\geq 0} I^d_d.$

If condition 1. is true for a subset $S\subset A[x]$, is $S$ is an ideal? I am struggling to find a counterexample.

Note that the above sets $I^n_d$ and $I^L$ are extensively used in the proof of Hilbert's Basis Theorem.

---

The counterexample is obvious, but I would like to see if we can add more fundamental properties other than condition 1. to get a stronger condition than ideals. I will re-edit the question, ask it later, and attach the link below.

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648414/proof-unification-attempt-for-hilberts-basis-theorem-over-ax-and-ax) is the new question post. The above thought will be used in a similar way.

Comment: Can we really hope to learn anything about the ideals of $\mathbb Q[x]$ from the ideals of $\mathbb Q$?  There are a great variety of ideals of $\mathbb Q[x]$ and the information you get from the trivial ideals does not seem up to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $A = \mathbb{Z}$, $S := \mathbb{Z}[x] - \{2(x+1) \}$.

$S^n_d = \mathbb{Z}$ forany $n,d \geq 0$.

Maybe you should post conditions on $S$ instead of $S^n_d$.